# how to select value from database and loop row according to user inserted value

Tags: php

table name --- pagination
column name ---- pageno

i am inserting pageno in database 
for ex--- 3 or 5 pr 7 etc...

**My question is: how do I select a value from a database and loop through a certain number of row's determined by the value a user input's.**

**for ex---  if value in database is 5
then loop display 5 rows like wise.......plz suggest me..**

i hard coded the userinput below but i can not understand how to select it from database and get selected value in userinput variable.

```
<?php
        $userinput = 3;     
        ?>
         <?php
            for($i=0; $i<$userinput; $i++)
            {
            ?>

        <tr>                    
          <td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i+1;?></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT pageno FROM pagination';

mysql_select_db('myapp');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Number :{$row['pageno']}  <br> ".

         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
for($i=0;$i<$row['pageno'];$i++)
echo "Fetched data successfully\n<br>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting values from both tables in your select query...